# Setting postgres datetime column to nil in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I'm writing a rails migration that populates a `premium_from` datetime column in a postgres table.

I have no problem with the population, but I'm stuck writing a rollback method for the migration, as either rails or postgres is seemingly just doing nothing when I attempt to change the datetime attribute back to `nil`.  I haven't been able to get any useful error messages out either, so I'm not at all sure what is happening.

Here's my most recent iteration (I tried acting on the accounts individually out of desperation, as nothing else seems to work either):

```
def self.down
  Account.where('premium_from is not null').each do |a| 
    a.update_attribute(:premium_from, 'null')
  end
end
```

This merrily runs for about 7 seconds and then leaves me with all the populated `premium_from` entries still intact, and I'm unable to find anything useful in google either.

**Does anybody know how to set datetime colum entries to `nil` in postgres?**

Or am I just overlooking something obvious?

Edit: up looks like this

```
csv.each do |row|
  if account = Account.premium.find_by_name(row.first)
    # This .find is necessary because .premium uses a join, meaning that it returns
    # read-only objects
    Account.find(account.id).update_attribute(:premium_from, Time.parse(row.last))
  end
end
```

Comment: Added it in.  The `premium_from` column was added in a previous migration if that's what you were wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would avoid referring to the `Account` class inside your migration, unless you have defined an `Account` class in the migration itself. This is always the sensible way to go because you may refactor the `Account` class and call it something different in the future, and in then this migration won't run. Something like `class Account < ActiveRecord::Base; end` should do.

Having that out of the way, I would recommend just using SQL in this case. It's simple enough and will perform way better. There's no need to bring all those records in, and build AR objects, just to issue updates. Here's how I'd do it:

```
execute "UPDATE accounts SET premium_from = NULL where premium_from IS NOT NULL;"
```

Comment: Boom, works perfectly.  I knew it would be something easy!  Regarding `Account` - that's pretty heavily baked into the application so there's really no chance of it being changed in future.  Good advice though and I'll bear it in mind in future.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
a.update_attribute(:premium_from, nil)
```

Does your column allows null values in postgres?

Comment: I did try that, it didn't work either - I really have no idea what's happening there.  hgmnz's SQL does the job nicely.